Thickness of delimiters
The amsmath package has a wonderful simple way to produces matrices with various delimiters, but the thickness of the delimiters are not uniform and when used together the display is not harmonious, like, for example:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The matrix
\(\begin{pmatrix}A&B&D\cr B&C&E\cr D&E&F\end{pmatrix}\)
has determinant
\(\begin{vmatrix}A&B&D\cr B&C&E\cr D&E&F\end{vmatrix}\)
\end{document}


Is there  a way to control the thickness of (simple) delimiters, like the one on {vmatrix}? What about the others?
The problem is persistent across font-desigs:
MTProII:

XITS:

Libertinus Math:


no that is not under the control of the latex package, it's simply a matter of the font design, You could try other fonts.

@DavidCarlisle I did try several fonts and the 'behaviour' seems to be consistent (or lack of it) across several fonts -- with the specific choice of {vmatrix}. I did edit the question to show more examples.

so presumably font designers see it as a common design feature, not a problem. As egreg shows you can use a different character (or a bold character) for | to get a thicker one]

For Latin Modern Math they are a bit thicker when they grow.

With Computer Modern fonts you can use \arrowvert:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newenvironment{bvmatrix}
  {\left\bracevert\begin{matrix}}
  {\end{matrix}\right\bracevert}

\begin{document}

The matrix
\(\begin{pmatrix}A&B&D\\ B&C&E\\ D&E&F\end{pmatrix}\)
has determinant
\(\begin{bvmatrix}A&B&D\\ B&C&E\\ D&E&F\end{bvmatrix}\)
\end{document}


With \usepackage{newtx}

With \usepackage{kpfonts}

With \usepackage{fourier}

With \usepackage{ebgaramond,ebgaramond-maths}

Comment
This doesn't work with stix2 or libertinust1math.

Any chances that similar tricks can be used for other fonts? I imagine that all these fonts have vertical bars on several thickness.

@TeXApprentice Just try…

@TeXApprentice I don't find that notation for the determinant particularly attractive, because it can confuse the reader with the absolute value, in particular for 1x1 matrices. It's old and out of fashion.

Just curious, which other notation for determinant you find any better? The notation is like that because determinant and absolute value share a few properties, multiplicative (|AB| = |A| |B|) and zero-value being two of them.

@TeXApprentice I prefix the matrix with “det”.

Oh no!! The similarity with absolute value is not to be lost. The distance to zero is a very important part of the concept of determinant.

... but talking about TeX, what are the possibilities of using this one paerticular character from CM when using other fonts?

@TeXApprentice Did you try? Anyway, there's no similarity with the absolute value, except for being multiplicative, but there are zillions of multiplicative functions.

@TeXApprentice I added some pictures obtained with a few math font packages.

I am trying, but did not succeed yet. There are a lot of other similarities in between the two, consider for example the inequality:
|A| + |B| ≤ |A+B| for positiive semidefinite matrices.
Cayley knew of that when he introduced the notaion in mid-1800's.
